# using livu (lib) with phonegap?

Tags: objective-c, ios, stream, cordova, rtmp

Livu has rtmp streaming functionality:
http://stevemcfarlin.com/livu/index.html

source (lib)
https://github.com/otmakie/LivuLib

I made a couple of iphone apps using software like phonegap.
How hard will it be to modify phonegap to make use of the livu (lib)?

I guess i have to edit the phonegap framework (which is written in objective C....)

I guess i have 3 options:

1. Practice objective c more and edit the phonegap framework
2. Hire someone to write phonegap plugin.
3. Practice objective c / hire programmer and go full native.

When i have compiled the livu lib and i have :

```
librtmp.a (from the rtmp xCode output)
libavcodec.a
libavcore.a
libavdevice.a
libavfilter.a
libavformat.a
libavutil.a
libswscale.a
```

Etc, how do i make use of them? (what are .a files?)

Comment: Hello, Writecoder. Have you succeeded with making iOS RTMP PhoneGap plugin or used some native solution? I wonder if it's possible to make PhoneGap RTMP broadcasting plugin, now in 2015 there's still no such a plugin on http://plugins.cordova.io or somewhere else in google search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably going to need to make a plugin for PhoneGap to interface with the live library.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins

Here are some tutorials on making plugins for PhoneGap:

http://hiediutley.com/2011/04/15/phonegap-tutorial-series-6-writing-your-own-plugin/