# Finger print hardware with cordova library?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, fingerprint

In one of our application we are planning to provide finger print recognition functionality (Note : we are not going to use mobile devices inbuilt fingerprint mechanism, we will be using external fingerprint hardware with usb connection to phone). After reading some articles online all the SDK's & APIs provided will be specific to a hardware manufacturer. Also they provide different SDKs for each OS which is ok, But no hardware manufacturer has any cordova plugin ( At least some I have read about ). Also most of the Hardware manufacturers don't have SDK's for iOS.

My question is is there any such universal cordova plugin. Or are there any such hardware manufacturers who has there own cordova plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

Publicly available plugin are these [link1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fingerprint-login) and [link2](http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/eddyverbruggen/cordova-plugin-touchid). But this handles inbuilt mobile hardware.

But in your case as you are using **external fingerprint hardware with usb connection to phone**, you may need to create your own custom plugin with an SDK which should be provided by that specific hardware vendors for variety of platforms.

Post which you will be able to invoke this plugin features from hybrid application.

A sample custom cordova plugin is [this github sample](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin) which handles multiple platforms (`iOS` , `Android` , `Windows`   etc)

Flow will be like as follows

> Hybrid application **>>** Call's method in Plugin **>>** Invokes Java Script
>   Bridge which has all methods defined **>>** According to platform specific
>   implementation features are invoked

Comment: By this you mean if a hardware manufacturer provides native API support for Android & iPhone then using that support I need to create a cordova plugin ?

Comment: Exactly. In-fact i have done the same in one of my projects.

Comment: Check this answer for the steps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974950/custom-cordova-plugin-creation-for-ionic2-project