# WebView Javascript injection doesn't work in Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, cordova-plugins, cordovawebview

I am trying to develop a Cordova plugin which can inject external JavaScript to the CordovaWebView. But I am not able to succeed.

I tried the same in MainActivity which extends CordovaActivity it works fine.

Heres what I did.

WebAppInterface class

```
private class WebAppInterface {

    private final Context context;

    WebAppInterface(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toastMsg) {
        Toast.makeText(context, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Injection Code

```
    WebSettings webSettings = ((WebView)appView.getEngine.getView()).getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(webView.getContext()), "android");

    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:android.showToast('Toast 1')");
```

Coming to cordova I made the plugin called MyPlugin extending CordovaPlugin and overided execute method.

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    if ("showLog".equals(action)) {
        Log.d("showLog", "showLog");
        return true;
    }

    if ("showToast".equals(action)) {

        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                WebView webView = (WebView) UnfoldPlugin.this.webView.getEngine().getView();
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(webView.getContext()), "android");

                webView.loadUrl("javascript:android.showToast('Hello World')");
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have written the UnfoldPlugin.js as well calling the cordova.exec method. Both the actions "showLog" and "showToast" gets called but not able to succeed in getting the toast via javascript injection.

Is this the problem of Cordova which doesn't allow external javascript injection via plugin?

How do i solve this problem? Help.

**Edit**

> however javascript:window.alert('Hello World') works

```
    @Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    if ("showToast".equals(action)) {

        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.alert('Hello World')");
            }
        });
        callbackContext.success();
        return true;
    }
```

I think the addJavascriptInterface is not working with Cordova Plugin.

Comment: Will the accepted answer be your help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974950/custom-cordova-plugin-creation-for-ionic2-project

Comment: no. didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of research i found the answer. Hope it might help someone.

The addJavascriptInterface method needs to be called inside the initialize.

```
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
        WebView webView = (WebView) UnfoldPlugin.this.webView.getEngine().getView();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(webView.getContext()), "android");
    }
```

Then webView.loadUrl() with any javascript tag can be used.